# Is it has '\0' at the end after convert the NSString to char in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get the text from `TextField` and convert to the `char` like the following:

```
    const char *TEXT;

    TEXT = [[_data text] UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"TEXT = %s" , TEXT);
    NSLog(@"strlen(TEXT) = %lu" , strlen(TEXT));
```

When I input the `abcde` in `textfield` , and the log show

```
TEXT = abcde
strlen(TEXT) = 5
```

If I want to send `TEXT` by `TCP` , should I add the `'\0'` by myself ? of it already has '\0' at the end ?

Comment: If it weren't null-terminated, then `strlen()` could not calculate its length. As to whether you should send the null terminator by TCP, that depends entirely on the application protocol that your program and the remote program have agreed to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It contains, you don't need to add a null terminator (`\0`).

Answer (score 1):

As it says [in the documenation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/UTF8String):

> UTF8String
>
> A null-terminated UTF8 representation of the string. (read-only)

So it's already null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

the `strlen` function counts the length of the contents, not including the null at the end. The actual length of the data in your `TEXT` variable is one byte longer (for the null)

BTW, you should follow Cocoa naming conventions. Variables (and method names) should be lower case, with words after the first word capitalized ("camel case", as it's sometimes called, e.g. "capitalizedLikeThis")

Class names should start with an upper case character and then follow the same camel case rules. (e.g. "ThisIsAClass")